# What is the inverse of the numpy cumsum function?

Tags: python, numpy, cumsum

If I have `z = cumsum( [ 0, 1, 2, 6, 9 ] )`, which gives me `z = [ 0, 1, 3, 9, 18 ]`, how can I get back to the original array `[ 0, 1, 2, 6, 9 ]` ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
z[1:] -= z[:-1].copy()
```

Short and sweet, with no slow Python loops. We take views of all but the first element (`z[1:]`) and all but the last (`z[:-1]`), and subtract elementwise. The copy makes sure we subtract the original element values instead of the values we're computing. ([On NumPy 1.13 and up](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/release.html#ufunc-behavior-for-overlapping-inputs), you can skip the `copy` call.)

Comment: I don't think this works, I'm getting this error message:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'

Comment: @Pedro: That's because you're using a list instead of an array. Despite the question's notation, `np.cumsum` returns an array.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is brilliant!  I imagine this is what is going on behind the scenes for np.diff. If not, maybe it should be.

Comment: As a person not very familiar with Python syntax, I'm a bit lost as to what's going on here. I'd love to see an explanation in the question! :)

Comment: @JeffBridgman: It's a very NumPy-specific way of doing things, so general Python syntax knowledge wouldn't help much. Particularly, if you tried this with `z = [ 0, 1, 3, 9, 18 ]` like the question says, you'd just get an `AttributeError`, since `z` really has to be a NumPy array instead of a list. (`np.cumsum` gives an array, so for the purposes of inverting `np.cumsum`, this code works fine.) I'd recommend checking out the [NumPy tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html), particularly the "Basic Operations" and "Indexing, Slicing and Iterating" sections.

Answer (score 15):

The following preserves the first element, too:

```
np.diff(z, prepend=0)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`np.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) to compute elements `1...N` which will take the difference between any two elements. This is the opposite of `cumsum`. The only difference is that `diff` will not return the first element, but the first element is the same in the original and `cumsum` output so we just re-use that value.

```
orig = np.insert(np.diff(z), 0, z[0])
```

Rather than `insert`, you could also use `np.concatenate`

```
orig = np.concatenate((np.array(z[0]).reshape(1,), np.diff(z)))
```

We could also just copy and replace elements `1...N`

```
orig = z.copy()
orig[1:] = np.diff(z)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep `z`, you can use `np.ediff1d`:

```
x = np.ediff1d(z, to_begin=z[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

My favorite:

```
orig = np.r_[z[0], np.diff(z)]
```

Comment: Why is this your favourite?