# Pandas - revert a cumsum with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

Is there a way to get original column back from column which is a cumsum() of the original column?

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Original': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, np.NaN, np.NaN,4, 0, 0],
                   'CumSum': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 7, 7, np.NaN, np.NaN, 11, 11, 11]})
```

In the above example df, Is it possible to get original column just using the CumSum column?

In my original dataset, I have a column similar to CumSum column and I want to get the original. I tried to find an inbuilt function that can do but haven't found any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Pandas - Unroll / Remove Cumulative Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452024/python-pandas-unroll-remove-cumulative-sum)   [this answer may or may not help with NaNs]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666924/what-is-the-inverse-of-the-numpy-cumsum-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['Original2'] = (df['CumSum'].ffill().diff()
                   .mask(df['CumSum'].isna())
                   .fillna(df['CumSum'])
                  )
```

Output:

```
    Original  CumSum  Original2
0        1.0     1.0        1.0
1        0.0     1.0        0.0
2        0.0     1.0        0.0
3        1.0     2.0        1.0
4        0.0     2.0        0.0
5        5.0     7.0        5.0
6        0.0     7.0        0.0
7        NaN     NaN        NaN
8        NaN     NaN        NaN
9        4.0    11.0        4.0
10       0.0    11.0        0.0
11       0.0    11.0        0.0
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. For a python newbie like me, this was helpful, and I appreciate it. Just FYI, If the cumsum column is like this [1,1,1,4,5,5,5,NaN,10, 0, 0, 1, 3, NaN, 3, 4, 4......] then the above code will work but at the point where the cumsum column restarts counts. The original2 column will then have a negative number. 

Fixed it using below code but just wanted to understand if there was a better way.

`for row in df.itertuples():
        if df.at[getattr(row, 'Index'),'original2']<0:
            df.at[getattr(row, 'Index'),'original2'] = df.at[getattr(row, 'Index'),'cumsum']`